# Laravel: How to Export Dashboard data which is consist of graph Graph and Table to PDF

Tags: laravel, chart.js, pdf-generation

I am using Laravel 10, I have dashboard and few other pages that have **Graph that use ChartJS**. What I understand dompdf camnnot be use as it does not support Javascript.

I am try to use the **Browser Print Function** unfortunately it does not show properly, as it depend much on the resolution of the screen, Did try play around with the CSS but still the graph somewhat expended.

Try to look on the **phantomJS** but seem like it have been discontinued.

Below is the result if I am using the print function from the browser.

[image]

I want to make the graph is properly shown and friendly to any export pages, Default page target is A4